# Remove \n from text file

Tags: c#

I have a large text file as input :

```
Një
tjetër
qytetar
ka
rënë
pre
e
dhunës
nga
ana
e
efektivëve
të
policisë
Ditën
e
sotme
një
i
ri
....
```

I want to display content of text file like(output):

```
Një tjetër qytetar ka rënë pre e dhunës nga ana e efektivëve të policisë Ditën e sotme një i ri ...
```

Here is my source code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileName = "C:\\Users\\Eric\\person.txt";
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
            {
                string s = String.Empty;
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                    Console.WriteLine("\t");
                }
            }
        }
```

But it does not work properly.

Comment: use `Console.Write`

Comment: For starters, Console.WriteLine(s) will always write a new line each time.  So you probably want to use a string variable and add each new line to your string with a space at the end.  Then write that string out after you have finished reading the file.

Comment: @Rakitić That has to be my favorite comment ever

Comment: @jpaugh78 that means creating a new string every time. Not a good way to do this if performance matters.

Comment: @Steve My mistake.  I was mostly wanting to note that WriteLine wasn't what he wanted, then I went on a tangent and forgot my main point.

Answer (score 4):

Console.WriteLine, as the name implies, writes a line readding the linefeed removed by Console.ReadLine. Just use Console.Write

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string fileName = "C:\\Users\\Eric\\person.txt";
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
    {
        string s = String.Empty;
        while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.Write(s);
            Console.Write("\t");
        }
    }
}
```

You can also reduce your code to a single line with

```
Console.Write(string.Join("\t", File.ReadLines("c:\\users\\eric\\person.txt")));
```

Comment: Absolutely love the one-liner. One thing I would note from the OP - the OP was putting a tab between the lines in code, yet the "desired output" was with just spaces. In case of this, just make note to use `" "` in the `Join` or `Console.Write`, instead of `"\t"`.

Comment: It could be just a copy/paste effect on the site editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can read your text file using

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\Eric\\person.txt");
text = text.Replace("\n", " ");
Console.Write(text);
```